# Problem with External Hard Disk

Tags: hard-drive, windows, files, ntfs

I'm experiecning a problem with my External Hard Disk.

When I plug my HDD in ubuntu it works. When I plug it in Windows, it also works. But when I transfer files from Ubuntu to HDD and then trying to acess them from Windows, no matter how I try, I get error messages. And when I'm able to acess them I cannot cpoy, or delete them through windows. They can only be modified through Ubuntu. I gave my HDD to a friend and she couldn't copy a folder I had created using Ubuntu. When I checked it using Windows 7, I clicked on the foldres' properties, and I saw that the "Read-Only" box was checked. I unckecked the box, but nothing. Only Ubuntu could modify the files in the folder, and copy or delete them from the HDD. How can I prevent ubuntu from making my files "read-only" for windows?

Comment: - What is the external HHD formatted as? - When in Ubuntu, do you manage the files as a normal user or as root? Have you tried using a USB stick, do you get the same problem?

Comment: with my USB everything works fine. I manage my files as a normal user. My HDD is formatted as NTFS...

Comment: Could it be that files are not written completely? I don't trust the progress bar when copying files, you may want to **Eject** the drive so all files are written fully.

Comment: so what would you suggest? Try to copy some files on my HDD and attempt to eject the drive, before start using them in Windows?

Comment: not the best solution, however try to give file permissions to all files on the HDD as follows `sudo chmod 777 *` (do it under Ubuntu). This will set files permissions to "the world".

Comment: @AnthieGeorgiadi Please edit your question to include what you've tried so far instead of replying directly in the comments.

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closeure. =)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that NTFS **WRITE support is experimental** for the Linux fs driver. The filesystem is probably broken. You could try running a fdisk from Windows on that volume and pray that it will repair it. Aside from that, you really shouldn't be using NTFS to share data between Windows and Linux, VFAT e.g. Fat32, is more than adequate.